# Trigger different task depending on filetype after watch trigger in boot?

Tags: clojure

In my build.boot file, i have a task pipeline that pretty much looks like this:

serve -> watch -> reload -> cljs -> less

The problem is, I don't want to compile less files when cljs files change and vice versa.

So how can i only call the cljs task or the less task?

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe there's something crucial I'm missing, but in my current setup (as I've described), when I touch say a less file, i have to wait ten seconds for the cljs task. It seems to be incremental in a way (the first cljs invocation takes way longer than ten seconds), but it's still recompiling something.

Comment: My task code looks like this:  (deftask build
  [p port PORT int "Which port to run on."]
  (comp
    (serve :port port :handler 'good-week.server.handlers/one-and-only :reload true) 
    (watch :manual false :verbose true)
    (reload)
    (garden :pretty-print true :styles-var 'good-week.style.core/good-style :output-to "public/css/good-style.css")
    (cljs :optimizations :whitespace :source-map true)
    (exists? :path "public/js/lib/main.js")
    (exists? :path "public/css/good-style.css")
    ))